# Solving a diophantine equation

Tags: diophantine-equations

Given the following function: $$f(x) = \sqrt{ (2155 - 6x)^2-4x}$$ where x is an integer and the function also generates an integer value, is there an algorithm to determine its integer solutions?

Comment: First, note that for most positive $x$, $(2155-6x)^2-4x>(2155-6x-1)^2$. Similarly, for most negative $x$, we can place a bound. So you only need to check a finite number of $x$ at worst.

Answer (score 2):

HINT : If you want to find $(x,y)\in\mathbb Z$ such that 
$$y^2=(2155-6x)^2-4x,$$
since we have
$$36 x^2-25864 x+4644025-y^2=0\Rightarrow x=\frac{6466\pm\sqrt{9y^2+12931}}{18},$$ 
we know that $9y^2+12931$ has to be a perfect square.

Hence, for some $z\in\mathbb Z$, we have $$9y^2+12931=z^2\iff (z-3y)(z+3y)=67\times 193$$
where $67,193$ are primes. Then, you can find $(y,z)$ to get $(x,y)$.

Comment: Is 12931 an arbitrarily chosen value?

Comment: It would be useful to say what $z$ is...

Comment: @Edward: No. I edited my answer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Thanks for pointing it out. I edited my answer.

Comment: @Nominal: Interestingly, your questions can be solved by finding $(X,Y)$ from $f(X,Y)\times g(X,Y)=N$ for some $N\in\mathbb Z$. So, you can find $(y,z)$ from $(z-3y)(z+3y)=67\times 193$, can't you?